# How can I paste from the clipboard?

Tags: shell, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, cloud, paste

Google cloud shell isn't letting me 'paste' what is in my clipboard.

I have tried using the 'send command' ctrl+v option, as well as tried with root.

I found it works with IE! Gives a message to allow clipboard access to the page (but a one time thing).

What am I missing?

Turns out this is not Chrome but my system settings. I tried on a different system and it worked!

Comment: Doesn't work on Firefox 64.0

Comment: Yep, Firefox 64. Starting chrome...

Answer (score 24):

For me, it does not work on Firefox version 60.2 on Linux (openSuSE Leap 15). But it works on Chromium 69.0.3497.100 (open SUSE Build) 64 bits. I believe it will also work with Google Chrome.

**Very important!!!** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> does not work! You must use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> to paste to Google Cloud Shell using Chromium.

**Note 1:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> did not work for me in Firefox

**Note 2:** I found a config option on top left of cloud shell frame, in the shape of a tool. There you can select `Terminal Preferences > Copy configuration` and will be an option to select `Copy and Paste with Ctrl+Shift+C/V`. Try enabling it if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> does not work for you.

**Note 3:** <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> works for me on Chromium, but not on Firefox.

In Firefox with this enabled **or** disabled copy and paste **does not** work. On Chromium it worked with this option enabled and disabled.

Comment: agreed Ctrl + Shift + v did not work for  Firefox .Use Shift+Insert will work for Firefox

Comment: Note 2 worked for me.

Comment: None of these options worked for me in Microsoft Edge. Instead I clicked on the App icon in the windows top left corner and pressed "Paste". This worked.

Answer (score 9):

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Firefox and had the same problem with Google Cloud Shell. I tried `Ctrl+V`, `Ctrl+Shift+V`, `Shift > Right Click > Paste` and `Terminal Preferences > Copy Configuration > Copy and Paste with Ctrl+Shift+C/V`.

It turned out the problem was connected with security settings of my Firefox. The option `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` had to be set back to default `true`.

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+c and ctrl+v will work. Simple!!!

Answer (score 0):

on GCP Cloudshell to copy use right click with mouse.
To paste use shift + insert key on cloud shell

Answer (score -4):

Turns out this is not even chrome buy my system settings. I tried on a different system and it worked with even Chrome!

Comment: That is not a solution I have this issue and want to get paste working in Ubuntu. Has anyone solved this?

Comment: Discovered it does work using Shift + Insert not Ctrl+v on ubuntu