# How to copy and paste clipboard contents from/into IBM Cloud Shell?

Tags: shell, cloud, ibm-cloud, copy-paste

I would like to be able to copy and paste the contents of my clipboard, respectively, from and into IBM Cloud Shell. There are existing solutions that work for other cloud systems but none that specifically applies to the cloud and shell in question.

A naive approach to resolve this issue would be to try the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> key combinations, i.e. the usual ways of copying and pasting contents. However, these do not work.

Comment: Which OS and browser are you seeing this limitation? I am using macOS + Safari and cmd + C to copy and cmd + V to paste works as expected.

Comment: I've seen it in Windows on Chrome and while using Ubuntu with Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> for **copying** and
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> for **pasting**.

---

The following approach should work on Chromium-based browsers and Firefox. Note that browsers commonly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to let the user access the console. Beware that Firefox has a setting that [limits the access to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63375676/8658651) which may or may not prevent the above solution from being applicable.